# Make a loop buttom in html video

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make a button that loops a video
I already have buttons for play/pause, and make video bigger and smaller.

https://imgur.com/a/1afc1CZ.jpg

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
    <video id="video1" width="420">
        <source src="video/yt-video-i-do-not.mp4" type="video/mp4">       
    </video>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
    <button onclick="loop()">Loop</button>
    <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
    <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
    <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  </div> 
  
  <script> 
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

  
  function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
      myVideo.play(); 
    else 
      myVideo.pause(); 
  } 
  
  function makeBig() { 
      myVideo.width = 900; 
  } 
  
  function makeSmall() { 
      myVideo.width = 320; 
  } 
  
  function makeNormal() { 
      myVideo.width = 420; 
  }
```

for now I made the button but it dosent do anything (ofc since I haven't any code attached to it

tbh I have no idea how to do it so im asking if someone know how to do it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Video element has a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) attribute.

If you you want to use a button to toggle this attribute you could do

```
function loop() {
    myVideo.toggleAttribute('loop');
}
```

Comment: THaaankkssss <3

Answer (score 0):

```
 function loop(){
    if(myVideo.loop == false){
      myVideo.loop = true
    }
  }
```